# Can a .net webservice be run in a medium trust enviornment

Tags: .net, web-services, medium-trust

Can a .net webservice that accepts values -- arrays, strings and returns values like bool and exceptions be run a "Medium" trust enviornment (Shared webhosting) -- and be called from any windows based or web based application -- do does the caller app have to be a special application?

Or does one have to do something special in the webservice (or is restricted to)?

### Environment

Webservice

.net Framework 3.5 SP1 as webservice
or
.net Framework 2.0 (compatible) as webservice

Caller
.net Framework 2.0 (compatible) windows app

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on what does the web service is doing. There are features that you cannot use in Medium trust. For example you cannot use Reflection and have unsafe code in Medium trust.

Comment: Not quite true, some Reflection actions are permitted, such as Assembly.Load() on trust-safe assemblies. Things like Reflection.Emit() are prohibited, however.